# How to take float value with pymodbus TCP library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbustcp

I am reading some values from a machine with pymodbusTCP library, but i have wrong values when i read floats.
The function to get the values is:

```
def ler_dado(endereco,tipo):
    if tipo == "float":
        valor = modbus.read_holding_registers(endereco,1*2)
        return [utils.decode_ieee(f) for f in utils.word_list_to_long(valor)][0]
    if tipo == "int":
        return modbus.read_holding_registers(endereco,1)[0]
```

The true value for example is 367 but read 366.
What can be wrong?

Comment: I removed the `pymodbus` library tag from your question because I realized your mean [pyModbusTCP-Library](https://pypi.org/project/pyModbusTCP/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an Endian conversion wrong for your system.  If you use the pymodbus.payload converter, you can change your endian conversions to get the right data.

```
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder

UNIT = 0x01
client = ModbusTcpClient(config_modbus['ip'],config_modbus['port'])
client.connect()
result = client.read_holding_registers(entry['address'],entry['count'],unit=UNIT)
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result.registers, Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
value = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
```

Comment: The library is:  https://pypi.org/project/pyModbusTCP , it is not the same as pymodbus library.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize, since you wrote pymodbus with a space, which the pymodbus library is a modbus over tcp library, which my examples shows.  maybe you can use it for your solution anyway, I've used it a bunch and it works great.  Either way, the problem is still likely Endian conversion of your floats, so you will have to find a way to decode it then if you don't want to use the binarypayloaddecoder I showed.